# Conditional filter in a stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have several filtering steps performed on some `List<a> listOfA` as follows:

```
listOfA.stream()
    .filter(methodAWithPredicate(someArg))
    .filter(methodBWithPredicate(someArg))
    .filter(methodCWithPredicate(someArg))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, I want the second filter to be conditional; i.e. it should be applied only if some condition (say x>0) is satisfied. What's a good way to do this inline in the code above, without having to make a whole if-else block like the following:

```
if (x>0) {
    return listOfA.stream()
            .filter(methodAWithPredicate(someArg))
            .filter(methodBWithPredicate(someArg))
            .filter(methodCWithPredicate(someArg))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
} else {
    return listOfA.stream()
            .filter(methodAWithPredicate(someArg))
            .filter(methodCWithPredicate(someArg))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Option 1:*

Like you're doing it in the question.

*Option 2:*

```
listOfA.stream()
    .filter(methodAWithPredicate(someArg))
    .filter(x > 0 ? methodBWithPredicate(someArg) : a -> true)
    .filter(methodCWithPredicate(someArg))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

*Option 3:*

```
Predicate<A> predicate = methodAWithPredicate(someArg);
if (x > 0)
    predicate = predicate.and(methodBWithPredicate(someArg));
predicate = predicate.and(methodCWithPredicate(someArg));

listOfA.stream()
    .filter(predicate)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Using the ternary in the last approach could have read cleaner in my opinion. `Predicate<A> completePredicate = methodAWithPredicate(someArg).and(x > 0 ? methodBWithPredicate(someArg) : p -> true).and(methodCWithPredicate(someArg));`

Comment: @Naman Using ternary is shown in option 2. Option 3 is to show how you can build a *composed* predicate when needed. The entire point was to show how you can build the predicate incrementally.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ternary operator

```java
return listOfA.stream()
        .filter(methodAWithPredicate(someArg))
        .filter(x > 0 ? methodBWithPredicate(someArg) : a -> true)
        .filter(methodCWithPredicate(someArg))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```